# Is there a way to remove a character by index from a string in R?

Tags: r, string

I have strings of DNA sequences such as:
"ACGTTATATTTATGTTTTGGGATTTTAGCAGGAATGATTGGTACTGCTTTCAGTATGTTAATTAGATTAGAGTTATCGGGACCGGGATCAATGTTAGGGGATATCATTTATACAATGTTATTGTTACTGCTCATGCTTTTGTTATGATTTTTTTTTTAGTAATGCCTGTGATGATTGGGGGGTTTGGGAATTGGTTAGTACCATTATATATTGGTGCCCCAGATATGGCATTCCCTCGATTAAATAATATAAGTTTTTGATTATTACCGCCGGCTTTAAG"

Is there a way I can remove the letters at specific positions e.g. at position 20 in R?

I think I may be able to use regex but I don't think I am getting the expression right.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to capture the characters until the 19, remove the 20th element and capture the remaining characterss

```
str2 <- sub("^(.{1,19}).(.*)", "\\1\\2", str1)
```

Or with a single capture group

```
sub("^(.{1,19}).", "\\1", str1)
```

---

Or another option is `str_sub`

```
library(stringr)
nchar(str1)
#[1] 280
str_sub(str1, 20, 20) <- ""
nchar(str1)
#[1] 279
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ACGTTATATTTATGTTTTGGGATTTTAGCAGGAATGATTGGTACTGCTTTCAGTATGTTAATTAGATTAGAGTTATCGGGACCGGGATCAATGTTAGGGGATATCATTTATACAATGTTATTGTTACTGCTCATGCTTTTGTTATGATTTTTTTTTTAGTAATGCCTGTGATGATTGGGGGGTTTGGGAATTGGTTAGTACCATTATATATTGGTGCCCCAGATATGGCATTCCCTCGATTAAATAATATAAGTTTTTGATTATTACCGCCGGCTTTAAG"
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, without the use of `regex` expression (and probably less straightforward tha @akrun's answer) you can use `strsplit` to extract each character of your string as a sequence, remove the 20th, and paste them back together.

```r
seq <- "ACGTTATATTTATGTTTTGGGATTTTAGCAGGAATGATTGGTACTGCTTTCAGTATGTTAATTAGATTAGAGTTATCGGGACCGGGATCAATGTTAGGGGATATCATTTATACAATGTTATTGTTACTGCTCATGCTTTTGTTATGATTTTTTTTTTAGTAATGCCTGTGATGATTGGGGGGTTTGGGAATTGGTTAGTACCATTATATATTGGTGCCCCAGATATGGCATTCCCTCGATTAAATAATATAAGTTTTTGATTATTACCGCCGGCTTTAAG"

nchar(seq)
[1] 280

seq2 <- paste(unlist(strsplit(seq,""))[-20], collapse = "")
nchar(seq2)
[1] 279
```

Comment: Thanks, I also eventually thought of a similar non-regex way : 
paste(substr(seq,1,19), substr(seq,21,length(seq)

Comment: You're welcome ;) I think there is multiple ways of achieving it, just pick the one you are more confortable with ;)